# Exclusion markers for gcov

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcov, gcovr

I'm using gcov to measure coverage in my C++ code. I'd like to be able to mark certain lines of source code so that they are excluded from coverage reporting when using gcovr. I know they exist because I stumbled across them once but now I can't find where I saw them.

I'm not using lcov to report coverage so references to such markers are no good to me.

Can anyone point me to the right place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured this out finally. The lcov exclusion markers are valid with gcovr.

> The following markers are recognized by geninfo:
>
> - LCOV_EXCL_LINE
>
>   - Lines containing this marker will be excluded.
> - LCOV_EXCL_START
>
>   - Marks the beginning of an excluded section. The current line is part of this section.
> - LCOV_EXCL_STOP
>
>   - Marks the end of an excluded section. The current line not part of this section.

You can also replace `'LCOV'` above with `'GCOV'` or `'GCOVR'`. They all work.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I am using gcovr 3.2 and I mark my lines of C++ with //LCOV_EXCL_LINE, but it still includes them. Which gcovr options are you using? I've tried LCOV/GCOV/GCOVR and I tried using ..._START and ..._STOP instead. Nothing works.

Comment: I'm using `gcovr` version 3.2. I run it with the following options: `gcovr --html --html-details -o <output-filename> -s -v -g -k -r <path-to-files> .`

Comment: Hmm still doesn't work. Probably has something to do with my directory structure. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps if you post a question detailing exactly what you're doing I might be able to see the problem. Or someone else might.

Comment: Good idea, I've posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618136/lcov-excl-start-stop-has-no-effect-when-using-gcovr