# LCOV_EXCL_START/STOP has no effect when using gcovr

Tags: gcov, lcov, gcovr

When I add LCOV_EXCL_START/STOP tags to my C++ code, it does not seem to have any effect on my gcovr report.

Does someone know why this occurs?

I have the following:

```
$ tree
.
├── build
├── include
│   └── a.h
└── tests
    └── test_a.cpp
```

and

```
$ cat include/a.h 
void f (bool x)
{
    // LCOV_EXCL_START
    if (x)
        throw 1;
    // LCOV_EXCL_STOP
}
```

and

```
$ cat tests/test_a.cpp 
#include "a.h"

int main ()
{
    f (false);
    return 0;
}
```

But line 5 `throw 1;` is included in the gcovr report, even though it is surrounded in exclude tags:

```
$ g++ -c -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC --coverage -I include ./tests/test_a.cpp -o ./build/test_a.o
$ g++ ./build/test_a.o -o ./build/test_a -lgcov
$ ./build/test_a
$ gcovr -r .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           GCC Code Coverage Report
Directory: .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                       Lines    Exec  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
include/a.h                                    4       3    75%   5
tests/test_a.cpp                               3       3   100%   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                          7       6    85%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: As a start, try adding `// GCOV_EXCL_LINE` after throw 1; - i.e. all on the same line. Does that make any difference?

Comment: @ksl I tried it, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Have you tried that *and* removing `// LCOV_EXCL_START` and `// LCOV_EXCL_STOP`? Clutching here..

Comment: @ksl Yes, I've tried that. Thanks for the suggestion. Strange isn't it?

Comment: @ksl However, if make the directory structure flat, it works.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @ksl No, it was never resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded to gcovr version 3.4, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check these couple marks (//LCOV_EXCL_START , //LCOV_EXCL_STOP) with gcov version: 9.4.0. And It works well